# Count the number of words and specify the lines

Tags: linux, bash

It is required to make a file with the number of words encountered (for example, `Word1` and `Word2`) from another file and specify the lines where these words occur in this format:

```
Word1: 35 [25, 50, 300, ...]    
Word2: 15 [10, 25, 65, ...]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can a word appear more than once on a line?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, this is exactly what needs to be taken into account

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question unfortunately lacks sample input files that demonstrates all the sorts of things you need to handle and the expected output based on them, so I'm just making up some stuff.

Given the files

`wordlist.txt`:

```
cat
dog
fish
horse
```

and `input.txt`:

```
There are three fish.
Two red fish.
One blue fish and a brown dog.
There are no matching words on this line.
Also there is no cat, only the dog. Oh, there is a white dog too.
There are doggies.
```

this perl script will print the matching words and their lines, including multiple matches of a word per line:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;
use English;

my %words;

open my $wordlist, "<", $ARGV[0];
while (<$wordlist>) {
    chomp;
    $words{$_} = [];
}

open my $text, "<", $ARGV[1];
while (<$text>) {
    while (my ($word, $positions) = each %words) {
        while (m/\b\Q$word\E\b/g) { # Match all occurrences of the word by itself
            push @$positions, $NR;
        }
    }
}

$OFS = ' ';
for my $word (sort keys %words) {
    my $positions = $words{$word};
    say "$word:", scalar(@$positions), join(',', @$positions);
}
```

Example:

```
$ perl words.pl wordlist.txt input.txt
cat: 1 5
dog: 3 3,5,5
fish: 3 1,2,3
horse: 0
```